# SQL exception column invalid, java sql statement

Tags: java, sql, oracle, spring-boot, jdbc

I have an issue when executing the following SQL statement using JAVA on a ORACLE database, it works with DBeaver/SQLdeveloper but during the java process I get the following error.  Any ideas ?

SQL Statement :

```
SELECT MIN(SUBSTR(t1.MONTH,1,4)) || 'A' || 'B' || 'CDE FGR' || ' ' || 'AT'
FROM table1 t1, table2 t2
WHERE t1.toto=t2.toto
AND t1.tata=t2.tata
AND t1.titi=t2.titi
AND t2.tutu = 'IMPACT_EUROPE_FLAG'
```

SQL error during java process :

```
org.springframework.jdbc.BadSqlGrammarException: Attempt to process next row failed; bad SQL grammar

nested exception is java.sql.SQLException: Invalid column name
```

Tables :

```
TABLE1  TABLE2 
--------------
MONTH   TOTO
TOTO    TATA
TATA    TITI
TITI    TUTU
TUTU
```

My java process, only the reader and stepbuilder :

```
 private Step insertBaseToFile() {
        return stepBuilderFactory.get("insertBaseToFile").<GenericRecord, GenericRecord>chunk(100).reader(baseReader())
                .writer(fileWriter()).build();
 }

private JdbcCursorItemReader<GenericRecord> baseReader() {

        JdbcCursorItemReader<GenericRecord> databaseReader = new JdbcCursorItemReader<>();

        String sql = null;

        sql = " SELECT MIN(SUBSTR(t1.MONTH,1,4)) || 'A' || 'B' || 'CDE FGR' || ' ' || 'AT' " +
                    "FROM table1 t1, table2 t2 " +
                    "WHERE t1.toto=t2.toto " +
                    "AND t1.tata=t2.tata " +
                    "AND t1.titi=t2.titi " +
                    "AND t2.tutu = 'IMPACT_EUROPE_FLAG'" 

        databaseReader.setDataSource(dataSource); //dataSource object from my class using JSON conf to get logs in to DB
        databaseReader.setSql(sql);

        return databaseReader;
}
```

Comment: Tip of today: Switch to modern, explicit `JOIN` syntax. Easier to write (without errors), easier to read (and maintain), and easier to convert to outer join if needed.

Comment: @a_horse_with_no_name I will update it

Comment: Can we see your table 1 & 2 ?

Comment: @TheBakker yes i'll update it

Comment: Assuming it works in SQL Developer, it might be struggling with the term 'MONTH'.    Try putting that in quotes, ie t1."MONTH"

Answer (score 0, accepted):

My bad. 
Everything works well it was an error from me using wrong variables names.

Answer (score 0):

My guess is that this is happening because the name of the column in your result is going to be:`MIN(SUBSTR(T1.MONTH,1,4))||'A'||'B'||'CDEFGR'||''||'AT'`

Try:

```
SELECT MIN( ... ) AS mycolumn
```